# Select a specific column in active-android

Tags: activeandroid

How to select a specific column in a table?

This returns a row..

`public static Model getData(String userId) {
        return new Select().from(Model.class).where("userId=?", userId).executeSingle();
    }`

Replacing it as :
`return new select("coloumnName").from(Model.class).where("userId=?", userId).executeSingle();` didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

### Provide a `String[]` to `Select`.

So you would do something like this:

```java
new Select( new String[]{ "columnName" } )
      .from( Model.class )
      .where( "userId = ?", userId )
      .executeSingle()
```